# jqueryUI - on drag start created element not acting as droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Using jquery's drag and drop, i am creating a element while i am starting my drag, while on the start i making a element and append to body, and making that as a droppable element..

i got a clue, using that i made my works, but it'not working any one suggest me the right way please..

this is my code:

```
$.fn.liveDroppable = function (opts) {
    this.on("mouseenter", function () {
        if (!$(this).data("ctDropInit")) {
            $(this).data("ctDropInit", true).droppable(opts);
        }
    });
};


$("#drag").draggable({

    cursor: "move",

    start:function(){

        if($("#dropBin").length){
            $("#dropBin").remove();
        }

        $('<div/>', {
            id: 'dropBin',
            title: 'Become a Googler',
            rel: 'external',
            text: 'Go to Google!'
    }).appendTo('#container');

    }
});

$('#dropBin').liveDroppable({
    hoverClass: "highlight",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        alert("Dropped!");
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yJqr2/)

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to make live/dynamic event handling but If you do like this problem been resolved. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mydhY/)

```
$("#drag").draggable({

    cursor: "move",

    start:function(){

        if($("#dropBin").length){
            $("#dropBin").remove();
        }

        $('<div/>', {
            id: 'dropBin',
            title: 'Become a Googler',
            rel: 'external',
            text: 'Go to Google!'
        }).appendTo('#container');

        $('#dropBin').droppable({
            hoverClass: "highlight",
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                alert("Dropped!");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: By the way, In my case i have 2 columns(both are working as separate modules) , column 2nd (droppable column) keep updating with new elements (itself), how can i make that droppable?